# Wrong Answer : Scuba diver SPOJ

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am trying [this problem](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SCUBADIV/) on SPOJ. Its basically a 0/1 knapsack.

Problem Statement: We are given **N≤1000** choice of air tanks having oxygen capacity, nitrogen capacity, and weight **O[i], N[i], and W[i]** respectively **O≤21,N≤79,W≤800**. We need enough tanks to fuel **t oxygen and a nitrogen** respectively to complete the dive. Find the **minimum total weight of tanks needed** to complete the dive.

I already implemented a 3-D dynamic programming solution. But I am getting Wrong Answer. Please help.

Source Code:

```
int dp[1002][23][81];   // to store subproblems
int ox[1002],nt[1002],wt[1002]; // ox: oxygen; nt: nitrogen; wt = weight of cylinder

void solve(int n, int oxy, int nit){ // n: no. of cylinders, oxy: oxygen required; nit: nitrogen required
  for(int i = 0; i <=n; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j <= oxy; ++j)
      for(int k = 0; k <= nit; ++k){
        if(i == 0)
          dp[i][j][k] = INF;
        else if(j == 0 && k == 0)
          dp[i][j][k] = 0;
        else
          dp[i][j][k] = min(dp[i-1][j][k], dp[i-1][max(j-ox[i], 0)][max(k-nt[i], 0)] + wt[i]);
      }
  printf("%d\n", dp[n][oxy][nit]);
}
```

Please help. [Complete Source Code](http://ideone.com/PrCFc9)

Comment: Does it work for the sample input ? What have you tried so far in order to debug this ?

Comment: Yaa it works for the sample input. I tried it for some other cases. Its working fine. Even looked at some other places. They all point to similar approach. I added link to complete source code. :(

Comment: You should edit the whole code into the question, it isn't that long although removing unused headers would make it a bit shorter, and you should add a language tag.

Comment: **You should edit the whole code into the question, it isn't that long although removing unused headers would make it a bit shorter**. Please elaborate. I am new here. Meanwhile I added the tag. Don't know much about posting for problems. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: There seems to be no step which initializes the array `dp` with the individual values from the given air tanks. Or is this contained in the last `else` branch? Please elaborate a little bit more on the recurrence equation.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Codor `dp[i][j][k] = min(dp[i-1][j][k], dp[i-1][max(j-ox[i], 0)][max(k-nt[i], 0)] + wt[i]);` In this line, the second arguement of min() does the thing. It will include the case, in whcih only that cylinder is included.

Comment: Strange. The recurrence ralation looks ok to me - it means that the `i`-th tank is *not included* and *included*, respectively, right?

Comment: Yes, just like knapsack.

Comment: Is it possible that `INF` is defined too small?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning infinite weight (cost) to all cases that use 0 tanks -- including, incorrectly, the case where `oxy = nit = 0`.  In that case (i.e. `dp[0][0][0]`) the weight assigned should be 0, since you can supply 0 oxygen and 0 nitrogen quite comfortably using 0 tanks.

This bug will cause your code to miss every minimal solution in which the tanks *exactly* cover the oxygen and nitrogen requirements with none left over, since all of these decision sequences end at the `dp[0][0][0]` subproblem after the last tank is added to the current partial solution.   To fix it, all you need to do is reverse the order of the first two `if` tests inside your innermost loop.